# What does it mean to combine the past (았) and future (겠) in a question?

Tags: grammar

[image: 빈 손으로 왔겠어?]

This example contains he past (았) and future (겠) in the same verb form.

In the past I've heard this used for supposition. I could understand this as a statement - meaning someone 'must have' or 'would probably have' come empty handed.

But what does it mean when used in a question in this way? (she doesn't seem to be empty-handed...)

Comment: “`-겠-`” is versatile, as well as “`would`” is. Implying the future tense is only one of its several usages.

Answer (score 7):

Just like English "will" or "would", -겠- frequently means assumption:

> 좀 있으면 비 오겠다 = It **may** rain soon.
>
> 아까 그 기차 탔으면 벌써 도착했겠다. = If we had taken the train, we **would have** arrived by now.

So, "빈손으로 왔겠다" would mean "[He] would have come empty-handed."

Now, the tricky part: "내가 빈손으로 왔겠어?" would be "would I have come empty-handed?"

It works basically in the same way in Korean as in English, in that it questions the assumption of the listener:

> Do **you** think I would have come empty-handed?

Also, 설마 is used to indicate "there's no chance" and makes sure that the whole question is understood as rhetorical (instead of a genuine question).  So, "설마 내가 빈손으로 왔겠어?" is something like:

> Come on, you don't think I would have come empty-handed, do you?

Answer (score 0):

1) 지금쯤 지혜는 부산에 도착했을거야 (추측 = guess )

Now, she may be in Pusan.

2) 지금쯤 지혜는 부산에 도착했겠네. (했 => 추측, 겠 => possibility in future tense)

That is, if we have some calculation or a clue about arriving, then we use
  겠. So we do not recommend that we would use 겠 frequently (since our opinion may be
  wrong).

3) 빈손으로 왔겠어 ?

Do you have a possibility that I came here with no present ? (Definitely, there is a present)

얘기 하자고, 만났겠니 ?

Definitely, I want activities beyond talking.

@ 들어가도 좋겠습니까 ? Do you allow that I would go into ?

@ http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000011963&supid=kku000016413

Comment: Perhaps the natural translation is "Would I have come empty handed?"

Comment: Would I have come empty handed = 빈손으로 왔어야 했지 ? = Next, I will not prepare present. In my thought, it is natural.